# Import HttpModule Error

Tags: angular, angular-http

In my component, I imported the following

```
import { Http, Response, URLSearchParams, HttpClient, HttpHeaders  } from '@angular/common/http';
```

but I am getting the error

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(35,9): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/strypeez/Dropbox/gosco-webNEW/gosco-webUPTODATE/node_modules/@angular/common/http"' has no exported member 'HttpModule'.
src/app/ownership-cost/ownership-form.component.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/strypeez/Dropbox/gosco-webNEW/gosco-webUPTODATE/node_modules/@angular/common/http"' has no exported member 'Http'.
src/app/ownership-cost/ownership-form.component.ts(8,16): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/strypeez/Dropbox/gosco-webNEW/gosco-webUPTODATE/node_modules/@angular/common/http"' has no exported member 'Response'.
src/app/ownership-cost/ownership-form.component.ts(8,26): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/strypeez/Dropbox/gosco-webNEW/gosco-webUPTODATE/node_modules/@angular/common/http"' has no exported member 'URLSearchParams'.
```

I was not getting the error when I used '@angular/http'; but the deprecation notes say to change it to '@angular/common/http'; What is causing the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `HttpClientModule`from the `@angular/common/http` and use the below statement

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
```

Reason: `HttpModule` is available in `@angular/http` package and it is deprecated

Update 1 : Based on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjzvlt)

Your import statements are wrong as few module level changes are made by angular and documented, modified import statements should look like

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
```

**[Updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r2m9bu)**

Comment: I made that change, but I am still getting the same errors with Http, Response and UrlSearchParams

Comment: it's the same "has no exported member" error in the question

Comment: not possible. can you create a stackblitz to reproduce?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjzvlt I am getting the same error in this stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported in your main module:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

[See here](https://angular.io/guide/http)